# Format exeption errors

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I have 2 activities. Activity A sends a Number to activity B and activity recieves and uses the Number. The problem is that activity B produces FormatExeption errors.

Activty A code:

```
EditText set_limit = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
Bundle set_limit_basic = new Bundle();
set_limit_basic.putString("limit_basic", String.valueOf(set_limit));
Intent Aintent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Aintent.putExtras(set_limit_basic);
startActivity(Aintent);
```

Activity B code:

```
Bundle set_limit_basic = getIntent().getExtras();
if (set_limit_basic != null) {
        String B_string = set_limit_basic.getString("limit_basic");
        if ( B_string .trim().length() == 0){
        limit_number = Integer.parseInt(B_string);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if ( B_string .trim().length() > 0){` instead of `== 0`?

Comment: Can you post the error to see on which line it occurs?

Comment: Do what Ted says above . And also you need to use `set_limit.getText().toString` to get String from edittext . ad make sure the imput type is as `number`.

Comment: I just copied your code to 2 new activities and it's working without any errors. So the problem must be somewhere else. Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: It says caused at parse int

Comment: @Micer run the code, you will surely get the exception at runTime !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points:

1. You shouldn't be converting `set_limit` to a string; `set_limit` is an `EditText` widget. Instead, you should be putting the *contents* of the view (the text it is displaying).
2. There's no reason to explicitly construct your own extras bundle. Just use one of the `putExtra` methods defined in the `Intent` class.
3. The error checking is probably better handled in activity A instead of activity B.
4. You seem to have a logic error in activity B, in that you are only attempting to parse the limit number when the trimmed text is empty. That seems backwards.

Putting all this together, I'd rewrite your code as follows:

Activity A:

```
EditText set_limit = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
CharSequence text = set_limit.getText();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    // handle case of no text
} else {
    try {
        int limit_number = Integer.parseInt(text.toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        intent.putExtra("limit_basic", limit_number);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // handle case of improperly formatted text
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
limit_number = getIntExtra("limit_basic", -1 /* or other default value */);

// or, if you want to explicitly check for presence of the extra:
if (hasExtra("limit_basic")) {
    limit_number = getIntExtra("limit_basic", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `1st Activity` you are trying to use `String.valueOf(edittext);`

- ( `set_limit` is a variable of type `EditText` so the string value will be `@djfjckckc78` something like this...which is surely not a number)

try

```
    String.valueOf(set_limit.getText().toString());
```

i.e,

```
    set_limit_basic.putString("limit_basic",String.valueOf(set_limit.getText().toString()));
```

and also in `Activity B`,

```
    if ( B_string .trim().length() >  0){ 
    }
```

> If you try to convert `String.valueOf(variable)` to a **number** it will throw a `NumberFormatException` at runtime because that string aint a number !!

Comment: i have eddited the answer please check @ManosRasidakis